# XML parser error when running a saxonb-xslt process

Tags: linux, xml, debian-stretch, parser

I am processing an XML document with **saxonb-xslt**, the command look like so:

```
saxonb-xslt -s:Transform.xsl -xsl:Transform.xsl -xi:on -ext:on
```

and I get this error:

> Error 
>     The XML parser reported one or more errors
>   Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

I need to troubleshoot this problem. How can I get more information about this error?

Background information:

- I am running saxonb-xslt (v. Saxon 9.1.0.8J) on Debian 9.
- The stylesheet compiles just fine with Oxygen on a windows machine, so I suppose the problem is with the XML parser saxonb-xslt uses on my linux machine.

Comment: could be the charset

Comment: Thanks @dandavis , this was worth a try. I tested the stylesheet with UTF-8 and then UTF-16, but I still got the same error message.